# Is dark matter needed to explain the orbit of a satellite galaxy around its main galaxy?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, dark-matter

Do we need to invoke the existence of dark matter to explain the orbital distance of a sample satellite galaxy? Or is the observed visible matter enough to be able to justify the gravitational attraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do! Actually the experiment can be used to find out about the dark matter content of the host galaxy. To give you a typical example consider the Milky Way (MW) and the Sagittarius (Sgr) dwarf galaxy. Sgr is being destroyed by the MW's gravitational potential, and the stars form a stream visible in surveys such as SDSS

[image]

You can try to use the orbit tracked by the stream to recover structure of the gravitational potential generated by the MW. The result is that the mass is around $10^{12}~M_{\odot}$, compare that with the $\sim10^{11}~M_{\odot}$ in baryons!

Comment: As an additional comment to this, the orbit of satellite galaxies can still be explained by other means, e.g. modified gravity. However, these approaches typically encounter problems at other fronts (CMB and microlensing experiments of bullet cluster strongly support the dark matter hypothesis and disfavor most modified gravity theories that could explain galaxy rotation curves / satellite galaxy orbits).